# Show mounted btrfs mounting options?

Tags: command-line, btrfs

I've recently switched to btrfs for better compatibility with Windows 10 (for which a third-party driver is available). The btrfs partition (on a SATA SSD) was mounted only for `/home`, and is formatted and mounted as a system partition when my operating system was installed (Pop OS 20.04).

After that I frequently encounter my chromium browser freezing up for a few seconds, sometimes it even leads to OS perceiving it as unresponsive process and prompt to kill it.

I wonder if it is caused by the btrfs not being mounted using the optimal option (with -o ssd and --autodefrag enabled). But I don't want to take the risk to mount it again and lose access to my home directory.

Is there a way to list all the status quo mounting option using the btrfs commandline tool?

Comment: Idk, but `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab` will.

Comment: thanks a lot! mount indeed is the right command: mount | grep home
/dev/sda1 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modern and arguably much nicer way is `findmnt`:

```
$ findmnt /
# TARGET SOURCE                FSTYPE OPTIONS
# /      /dev/mapper/cryptroot btrfs  rw,relatime,compress-force=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,autodefrag,subvolid=5,subvol=/
```

Comment: Indeed, much better